# mysql query to retrieve count using a single query

Tags: mysql

I have the below result on executing the below query:

```
select * from db1.user_details;

Dept_Id     Form_Id     Status
-----------------------------------------------
dept1       Form1       CD1
dept1       Form2       CD1
dept1       Form3       CD2
dept2       Form1       CD1
dept3       Form3       CD2
dept3       Form1       CD1
dept3       Form2       CD3
----------------------------------------------
```

Here CD1 is "received", CD2 is "In Process", CD3 is "Rejected".

Now i want to find out the total no of Received, In Process and Rejected of each dept's

The result should be like:

```
Dept_Id Received    In Process  Rejected
-------------------------------------------------------------
dept1       2       1             0
dept2       1       0             0
dept3       1       1             1
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not able to write the mysql query for this. Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUM()` with condition to get the count ,using condition in SUM will result as a boolean and you can get your count

```
select Dept_Id,
SUM(`Status`='CD1') Received,
SUM(`Status`='CD2') In_Process,
SUM(`Status`='CD3') Rejected
from Table1
GROUP BY Dept_Id
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fa1c/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Dept_Id,,
    SUM(status = 'CD1') as Received,
    SUM(status = 'CD2') as In_Process,
    SUM(status = 'CD3') as Rejected
FROM 
    tablneme
GROUP BY Dept_Id
```

### [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e045/4)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IF` control flow statements, like this:

```
SELECT Dept_Id,
  SUM(IF(Status='CD1', 1, 0)) AS Received, 
  SUM(IF(Status='CD2', 1, 0)) AS InProcess,
  SUM(IF(Status='CD3', 1, 0)) AS Rejected
FROM db1.user_details
GROUP BY Dept_Id
```